# Converting the equation of the line to the vector and symmetric forms of the equation.

Tags: vectors

Does anyone know how to convert the equation of the line to the vector and symmetric forms:

$x=-1-2t$

$y=1+3t$

$z=2+t$

Comment: $ \frac{x+1}{-2} = \frac{y-1}{3} = \frac{z-2}{1}= t  $ . I hope this is the symmetric form.  The vector form would be $ \vec{o}= -1i + 1j + 2k + k( -2i + 3j + 1k) $

Answer (score 1):

The vector form is given simply rewriting the three equations in vector form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\1\\2
\end{bmatrix}+t
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\3\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

for the symmetric form find $t$ from the three equations:
$$
t=\frac{x+1}{-2} \qquad t=\frac{y-1}{3} \qquad t=z-2
$$ 
so you have:
$$
\frac{x+1}{-2}=\frac{y-1}{3}=z-2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach

**EQUATION OF LINE IN VECTOR FORM**
$$
\vec{r} = \vec{a} + \lambda \vec{b}
$$

and in **SYMMETRIC FORM**
$$
\frac{x-x_{1}}{a}=\frac{y-y_{1}}{b}=\frac{z-z_{1}}{c}
$$
we can write it also as
$$
\frac{x-\left ( \vec{a}\cdot  \hat{i}\right )}{\vec{b}\cdot  \hat{i}}=\frac{y-\left ( \vec{a}\cdot  \hat{j}\right )}{\vec{b}\cdot  \hat{j}}=\frac{z-\left ( \vec{a}\cdot  \hat{k}\right )}{\vec{b}\cdot  \hat{k}}
$$

By comparing it with the given data

$$
\\ \frac{x+1}{-2}=\frac{y-1}{3}=\frac{z-2}{1} \\ \vec{a} = -\hat{i} + \hat{j} + 2\hat{k} \\ \vec{b} = -2\hat{i} + 3\hat{j} + \hat{k}
$$

**ANSWER**
$$
\\ \vec{r} = -\hat{i} + \hat{j} + 2\hat{k} +\lambda\left (-2\hat{i} + 3\hat{j} + \hat{k}  \right )
$$